# Angular js ng-init - value field not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose i have the following code, where i'm initializing text box value with some value.

```
<div id="Mydiv">   
<input type="text" id="text1" ng-init="Some value" ng-model="text1" value="some value"/> 
</div>
```

And this text box value can be changed at any point.

At some point/operation in the angular js script we are executing following code.

```
var fnLink = $compile("#Mydiv");
fnLink($scope);
```

Here the problem is, the updated value in the textbox is going off and initialized value with `ng-init` is coming.

For example : if i change the text box value to `Jordan`, after executing above code, the value is changed to `"some value"`

But in the watcher, i can see that model value is still `"Jordan"`. Only value feild of textbox is changing.

Guys, anyone please suggest me, how to maintain updated value in the textbox.

Is that a problem with ng-init?

Comment: I believe you could write ng-init="text1 = 'Some value'"

Answer (score 1):

From the angular docs (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So apparently you aren't using it appropriately and should move your logic into a controller.

Comment: We can't change the structure now. Can u please provide alternative.

Comment: You cannot change the structure of what?

Comment: I can not change the code now. I have used this ng-init in many places.